# Surface integral: double versus single integral notation

Tags: notation, vector-analysis

The total flux through a surface *S* can be defined as follows:
$\iint_{S}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\right)\,dS$  (Eq. 1)

Some text books appear to use a different notation:
$\int_{S}\left(\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\right)\,dS$  (Eq. 2)

Is Eq. 2 just a more compact notation of Eq. 1, or do both equations actually differ? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, 1 is a more verbose version of 2.

Comment: they are the same. The first is classical notation.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your prompt replies.